# Is it possible to do a silent install for Flash Develop?

Tags: windows-7

I can't find any info about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  Reference their wikipage on [installation](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Installation)